# signal.medfilt2d is getting ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to get the background of a noisy image based on this code https://www.kaggle.com/rdokov/background-removal

But, I'm getting ValueError. How to resolve this?

```
import glob
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
a = cv2.imread(glob.glob('lp_train/*.jpg')[0])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a2 = np.asarray(a)/255.
aa = signal.medfilt2d(a2, 11)
plt.imshow(aa)
plt.show()
```

**Error: ValueError: object too deep for desired array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.jpg has 3 channels, so you are sending 3-dimensional array but medfilt2d accepts 2d array.

Two ways you can solve this.

1. Just read as a grayscale image

```
import glob
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
a = cv2.imread(glob.glob('lp_train/*.jpg')[0], 0)  # grayscale, single channel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a2 = np.asarray(a)/255.
aa = signal.medfilt2d(a2, 11)
plt.imshow(aa)
plt.show()
```

2. Take a specific channel (R/G/B)

```
import glob
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
a = cv2.imread(glob.glob('lp_train/*.jpg')[0])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a2 = np.asarray(a)/255.
aa = signal.medfilt2d(a2[:,:,0], 11) # a specific channel
plt.imshow(aa)
plt.show()
```

Both should work.

Comment: yes, it's working now? but, how can I get for all the channels?